# Clarification on Periodicity of Markov Chains

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Given the Markov Chain: 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0.3 & 0 & 0 & 0.7 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0.4 & 0 & 0.6\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
The question asks to find the periodicity of each class, and I figured out all the states except state 1 and 3. I believe the period of both of them are 0 i.e. no period since we can't return to either 1 or 3 if we start at these states. 
However, since all states communicate with itself, does it mean the period of 1 and 3 is 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, if the Markov chain starts either in state 1 or state 3 it will never comeback to that state. Such states are called non-return states. Every state communicates with itself in the sense of zero-step transition probabilities, defined by
\begin{equation*}
    p_{ij}^{(0)}=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
                          1 & if & i=j \\
                          0 & if & i\ne j \\
                        \end{array}\right.
\end{equation*}
However, periodicity of a state $j$ is defined as the gcd of a non-empty set of all those $n>0$, for which $p_{jj}^{(n)}>0$. Period of a state is not defined otherwise. Clearly, period is not defined for states other than 2 and 4, in the given transition probability matrix. 
States 2 and 4 form a closed-communicating class with periodicity 2.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, for all $n>0$, $p^{(n)}_{11} = p^{(n)}_{33}=0$ thus, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Periodicity), the period is undefined (or $+\infty$ if you want, it's a matter of convention).